# ASP process list of labels in a loop

Tags: asp.net

I have a table with several labels lbl1, lbl2...., lbl6... numbered serially

I want to access them in a for loop using a index. Here's my puedocode

```
//PuedoCode:
int _NUMCOUNT = 6;
string labelname;
string[] strArray = new string[_NUMCOUNT];
//Store some values in strArray

for (int i=0; i<_NUMCOUNT; i++)
{
     labelname = "lbl" + (i + 1).ToString();
     labelname.Text = strArray[i]
 }
```

Can this be done? I don't want to use a placeholder & add the labels into it. I already have the labels in a formatted table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the replies. It pointed me in the right direction.

I had to modify the code to

```
ContentPlaceHolder myContent = (ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1"); //ASP page has master & this is the content page
string lblName = "lbl" + (i + 1).ToString();
Label lblControl = myContent.FindControl(lblName) as Label;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use FindControl Method,

```
//PuedoCode:
int _NUMCOUNT = 6;
string labelname;
string[] strArray = new string[_NUMCOUNT];
//Store some values in strArray

for (int i=0; i<_NUMCOUNT; i++)
{
   Label control=(Label)tab.FindControl("lbl"+i);  //Assume that the "tab" is container (table) control.
   if(control!=null)
       control.Text = strArray[i];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Control.FindControl Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx):

> Searches the current naming container for a server control with the
>   specified id parameter.

```
Label label = FindControl("lbl" + i.ToString()) as Label;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int _NUMCOUNT = 6;
        string labelname;
        string[] strArray = new string[_NUMCOUNT];
        //Store some values in strArray

        for (int i = 0; i < _NUMCOUNT; i++)
        {
            Label lbl = (Label)yourTable.FindControl(String.Format("lbl{1}", i + 1)); //yourTable is the id of table that contains labels
            if (lbl != null)
            {
                lbl.Text = strArray[i];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to do that. Just put the labels in a container of some sort (e.g. Panel or Placeholder), and do something like this:

```
<asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" />
    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" />
</asp:Panel>
```

And in your code:

```
foreach (Label label in Panel1.Controls.OfType<Label>())
{
    label.Text = "Something";
}
```